# Pre-calculate the winning combinations for an n-sized tic tac toe board using C++ functional programming

Tags: c++, functional-programming, comparative-review, tic-tac-toe

This code pre-calculates the winning combinations for an n-sized tic tac toe board.

I first created my function using an imperative approach.  This is just how I naturally write code most of the time.  I then tried to think about the problem using a "What I want to accomplish?" approach, rather than "What do I want it to do?"  In the end I think I still ended up with an imperative approach, just using STL algorithms as loops.

Imperative approach:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rules3(const int x){
    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int>> seqs;
    for(int n=0; n<x; ++n){
        vector<int> seq;
        for(int m=0; m<x; ++m){
            seq.push_back(n*x+m);
        }
        seqs.push_back(seq);
    }
    for(int n=0; n<x; ++n){
        vector<int> seq;
        for(int m=0; m<x; ++m){
            seq.push_back(n+x*m);
        }
        seqs.push_back(seq);
    }
    vector<int> seq;
    for(int n=0; n<x; ++n){
        seq.push_back(n*x+n);
    }
    seqs.push_back(seq);
    seq.clear();
    for(int n=0; n<x; ++n){
        seq.push_back(x-1+n*(x-1));
    }
    seqs.push_back(seq);

    return seqs;
}
```

Getting more functional:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rules2(const int x){
    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int>> seqs;
    vector<int> iter(x);
    iota(iter.begin(), iter.end(), 0);

    for(auto n: iter){
        vector<int> seq;
        for(auto m: iter){
            seq.push_back(n*x+m);
        }
        seqs.push_back(seq);
    }
    for(auto n: iter){
        vector<int> seq;
        for(auto m: iter){
            seq.push_back(n+x*m);
        }
        seqs.push_back(seq);
    }
    vector<int> seq;
    seq.clear();
    for(auto n: iter){
        seq.push_back(n*x+n);
    }
    seqs.push_back(seq);
    seq.clear();
    for(auto n: iter){
        seq.push_back(x-1+n*(x-1));
    }
    seqs.push_back(seq);

    return seqs;
}
```

Functional approach? (still feels imperative):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rules1(const int x){
    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int>> seqs;
    vector<int> iter(x);
    iota(iter.begin(), iter.end(), 0);

    transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seqs), [&](const int& n){
        vector<int> seq;
        transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seq), [&](const int& m){
            return n*x+m;
        });
        return seq;
    });
    transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seqs), [&](const int& n){
        vector<int> seq;
        transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seq), [&](const int& m){
            return n+x*m;
        });
        return seq;
    });
    vector<int> seq;
    transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seq), [&](const int& n){
        return n*x+n;
    });
    seqs.push_back(seq);
    seq.clear();
    transform(iter.begin(), iter.end(), back_inserter(seq), [&](const int& n){
        //return (x-n-1)*x+n; // 6,4,2
        return x-1+n*(x-1); // 2,4,6
    });
    seqs.push_back(seq);

    return seqs;
}
```

Output when printing:

```
rules3
std::vector(0, 1, 2)
std::vector(3, 4, 5)
std::vector(6, 7, 8)
std::vector(0, 3, 6)
std::vector(1, 4, 7)
std::vector(2, 5, 8)
std::vector(0, 4, 8)
std::vector(2, 4, 6)
rules2
std::vector(0, 1, 2)
std::vector(3, 4, 5)
std::vector(6, 7, 8)
std::vector(0, 3, 6)
std::vector(1, 4, 7)
std::vector(2, 5, 8)
std::vector(0, 4, 8)
std::vector(2, 4, 6)
rules1
std::vector(0, 1, 2)
std::vector(3, 4, 5)
std::vector(6, 7, 8)
std::vector(0, 3, 6)
std::vector(1, 4, 7)
std::vector(2, 5, 8)
std::vector(0, 4, 8)
std::vector(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Is the Ranges library a possibility?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, I have been using boost in other areas of my code.  I have been wanting to experiment with that.  Did you have something specific in mind?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions.  This answers uses the [Range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) library and assumes

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

namespace view = ranges::view;
```

1. Please include the `#include`s and supply a small test program in the future.  You probably have written them anyway, so why not post them to save reviewers' time? :)
2. `int` may be too small for indexes.  Consider using `std::size_t`.  You can define a type alias for flexibility.

   ```
   using index_t = std::size_t;
   ```
3. The type `std::vector<std::vector<index_t>>` occurs many times.  Save time by writing

   ```
   using rule_t = std::vector<index_t>
   using rules_t = std::vector<rule_t>;
   ```
4. The concept "\$n \times n\$ board" only makes sense when \$n\$ is a positive integer.  Therefore, enforce the pre-condition \$n \ge 1\$.  Also, the name `x` is a bit vague.  `size` may be better.

   ```
   rules_t rules(index_t size)
   {
       if (size == 0)
           throw std::invalid_argument{"..."};
       // ...
   }
   ```
5. `rules(1)` currently returns `{{0}, {0}, {0}, {0}}`, which is definitely wrong.  It should return `{{0}}`.  Your general logic is "\$n\$ rows + \$n\$ columns + \$2\$ diagonals", which only applies to \$n \ge 2\$.  The easiest approach would be a special case:

   ```
   rules_t rules(index_t size)
   {
       // ...
       else if (size == 1)
           return {{0}};
   }
   ```
6. Following the previous bullet, why not make separate functions to make your logic clear?

   ```
   rules_t rules(index_t size)
   {
       // ...
       else {
           auto rows = rules_row(size);
           auto columns = rules_column(size);
           auto diagonals = rules_diagonal(size);
           return ranges::to<rules_t>(view::concat(rows, columns, diagonals));
       }
   }
   ```

   where `view::concat` concatenates the three vectors and `ranges::to` converts the result to the desired return type.  (Note that `view::concat` is disabled with rvalues to prevent dangling iterators, so we first store the subvectors.)
7. The `rules_row` function is easy to write:

   ```
   rules_t rules_row(index_t size)
   {
       return view::ints(index_t(0), size * size) | view::chunk(size);
   }
   ```

   `view::ints` generate a left-inclusive sequence of integers `{0, 1, 2, ..., size * size - 1}`, and `view::chunk(size)` breaks it into chunks each of size `size`.
8. The `rules_column` function is a bit tricky, because the Range library does not provide a function like `chunk` that splits like this.  We do have a function `stride`, so we can write a manual "loop":  (it took me quite a while to figure this out, so tell me if there is a better way!)

   ```
   rules_t rules_column(index_t size)
   {
       return view::ints(index_t(0), size) |
                  view::transform([=](index_t col) {
                      return view::ints(index_t(col), size * size) | view::stride(size);
                  });
   }
   ```

   `view::ints(index_t(0), size)` generates the column numbers.  Each of them is passed to the lambda.  The lambda returns the corresponding rule for each column.
9. The `rules_diagonal` function is moderately simple:

   ```
   rules_t rules_diagonal(index_t size)
   {
       return {
           view::ints(index_t(0), size) |
               view::transform([=](index_t r) { return r * (size + 1); }),
           view::ints(index_t(1), size + 1) |
               view::transform([=](index_t r) { return r * (size - 1); })
       };
   }
   ```

   Here, we always have two rules: one for the primary diagonal

   ```
   {0 * size + 0, 1 * size + 1, 2 * size + 2, ..., (size - 1) * size + (size - 1)}
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   {0, 1, 2, ..., size - 1} * (size + 1)
   ```

   and the other for the secondary diagonal

   ```
   {size - 1, 2 * size - 2, 3 * size - 3, ... size * size - (size - 1)}
   ```

   which is equivalent to

   ```
   {1, 2, 3, ..., size + 1} * (size - 1)
   ```
10. Putting everything together:

    ```
    #include <vector>
    #include <range/v3/all.hpp>

    namespace view = ranges::view;

    using index_t = std::size_t;
    using rule_t = std::vector<index_t>;
    using rules_t = std::vector<rule_t>;

    rules_t rules_row(index_t size)
    {
        return view::ints(index_t(0), size * size) | view::chunk(size);
    }

    rules_t rules_column(index_t size)
    {
        return view::ints(index_t(0), size) |
                   view::transform([=](index_t col) {
                       return view::ints(index_t(col), size * size) | view::stride(size);
                   });
    }

    rules_t rules_diagonal(index_t size)
    {
        return {
            view::ints(index_t(0), size) |
                view::transform([=](index_t r) { return r * (size + 1); }),
            view::ints(index_t(1), size + 1) |
                view::transform([=](index_t r) { return r * (size - 1); })
        };
    }

    rules_t rules(index_t size)
    {
        if (size == 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument{"A board cannot have size zero"};
        else if (size == 1)
            return {{0}};
        else {
            auto rows = rules_row(size);
            auto columns = rules_column(size);
            auto diagonals = rules_diagonal(size);
            return view::concat(rows, columns, diagonals);
        }
    }
    ```

    ([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Np1OSewSm5HTW2hr), tests the function for `size = 1, 2, 3, ..., 10`)

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at this.  You have given a lot to think about.